# Azure Comms to send emails

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

With the caveat that I see Azure.Communication.Email is pre-release, so perhaps it just doesn't work, but the following sample code just hangs. Any idea if Azure.Communication.Email works?

```
var connectionString = "endpoint=xxxx";

            // Authenticate the client
            EmailClient emailClient = new EmailClient(connectionString);

            EmailContent emailContent = new EmailContent("Welcome to Azure Communication Service Email APIs.");
            emailContent.PlainText = "This email message is sent from Azure Communication Service Email using .NET SDK.";
            List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress> { new EmailAddress("hello@test.com") { DisplayName = "Test Person" } };
            EmailRecipients emailRecipients = new EmailRecipients(emailAddresses);
            EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage("donotreply@test.com", emailContent, emailRecipients);

            try
            {
                SendEmailResult emailResult = emailClient.Send(emailMessage, CancellationToken.None);

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message)); }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");

            Console.Read();
```

Comment: Yes, it should be working fine. Can you please try it by using the following sample https://github.com/ealmuneyeer/AzureCommunicationEmailService.
Also, please make sure to configure your Azure Communication Services and Email Communication services correctly as mentioned in the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/create-email-communication-resource and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/connect-email-communication-resource

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

I followed this [MS-DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/send-email?pivots=programming-language-csharp) to send an Email using Azure communication service.

**NuGet Package:**

```
Azure.Communication.Mail - 1.0.0-beta.1
```

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Communication.Email;
using Azure.Communication.Email.Models;


var connectionString = "<Connection string of azure communication service>';

EmailClient emailClient = new EmailClient(connectionString);

EmailContent emailContent = new EmailContent("Welcome to Azure Communication Service Email APIs.");
emailContent.PlainText = "This email message is sent from Azure Communication Service Email using .NET SDK.";
List<EmailAddress> emailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress> { new EmailAddress("hihello.com") { DisplayName = "Friendly Display Name" } };
EmailRecipients emailRecipients = new EmailRecipients(emailAddresses);
EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage("DoNotReply@XXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azurecomm.net", emailContent, emailRecipients);
try
{
    SendEmailResult emailResult = emailClient.Send(emailMessage, CancellationToken.None);

}
catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message)); }

Console.WriteLine("Done");

Console.Read();
```

**Console:**

[image]

Make sure your azure communication service with domain is connected.

[image]

**Mail:**
The above code executed successfully by sending mail to recipient.

[image]